# Package Manager for a custom language

Tags: node.js, npm, package, package-managers

I'm creating a new programming language specific to our use cases. And I'm looking for an already available package manager I can reuse for dependency management of my language. I plan to use [npm](https://www.npmjs.org/) as the package manager because it's quite popular and easy to use.

For example, a package containing the new language might look like:

```sh
pkgA/
 helloworld.me # my language
 package.json
```

And with dependencies installed:

```sh
pkgA/
  node_modules/
    pkgB/
      hithere.me
      package.json
  helloworld.me
  package.json
  package-lock.json
```

In the code, language and its compiler will have its own way to resolve references.

```sh
# helloworld.me
> "hello world"
```

using dependency

```sh
# helloworld.me
import pkgB.hithere

> "hello world"
< hithere
```

I have been exploring answers to the following questions. It would be great and very helpful if you have already done something similar.

1. Can `npm` be used with any other language?
2. Is this a good or bad idea?
3. Are there any restrictions `npm` platform might have?
4. Are there any other package managers specifically designed as language agnostic? or do i have to build my own PM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research, I found this post - [Can I distribute non javascript files via npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47135991/can-i-distribute-non-javascript-files-via-npm)

Based on the terms, it looks like using npm for other incompatible languages is not allowed.

> Packages that are not functionally compatible with the npm command-line client. For example, a "package" cannot simply be a PNG or JPEG image, a movie file, or a text document uploaded directly to the registry. Using the Public Registry as a general purpose database is not allowed.